# django static files 404 error after migration

Tags: django, django-static

static folder path correct and it was all working before migration.

- index.html

```
{%load staticfiles%}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mycss.css"%}"/>
        <title>My first Django App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>{{somthin}}</h1>
    <img src="{% static 'images/zoro.jpg'%}" alt="Oops!No Image">

    </body>
</html>
```

after `python manage.py runserver` in terminal static files are showing 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure all these configuration you have in your settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

and in main urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and use `{% load static %}` tag in templates, also if you use double quote outside curly brackets, use single quote inside

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/mycss.css' %}"/>
```

Comment: Nope it didn't work, when i runserver all static files(image and css) load but didn't work in the browser

Comment: please post your directory structure

Comment: directoty structure added

Comment: your directory structure is not correct, you have to have separate static folder as well as template folders. Please follow any of django tutorials , for example https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django/

Comment: that was my mistake while creating directory structure here now it's corrected.

Comment: this was all working before i connected to the database so i don't think there is any error in code ,any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: why you keep two dbs?

Comment: that was all created by default by django after running `django-admin startproject project_name` and `python manage.py startapp app_name`

Comment: you might have used start project command twice, copy all your code and re create your app again with python manage.py start app your_app_name command, delete the inner db and app folder